# Count number of occurrences by the hour in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've tried searching but there doesn't seem to be an answer. Maybe I am googling wrong so I apologize, but basically for a table I need to count the number of rows that have a LogType of success, and group them hour by hour for a certain day... 1/27 for example.

So far I have this

```
SELECT dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, LogTime), 0) as Hour, LogType
  FROM [<production_db_name>].[dbo].[GPExportLog]
  where LogType like 'Success' and (LogTime BETWEEN '2021-01-27' and '2021-01-28')
```

Which produces a result that looks like this,

```
Hour, LogType

3-24-2021 17:00 Success
3-24-2021 17:00 Success
3-24-2021 17:00 Success
3-24-2021 18:00 Success
```

However, I need it to look something more like this,

```
hour, count
3-24-2021 17:00, 3
3-24-2021 18:00, 1
```

Comment: Which DB are you using? Please add the appropriate tag to your question

Comment: sorry, Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: `select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, LogTime), 0) as Hour, count(*) from ... where ... group by 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `group by` your calculated `Hour` column?

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, LogTime), 0) AS [Hour], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM GPExportLog
WHERE LogType like 'Success' AND (LogTime BETWEEN '2021-01-27' AND '2021-01-28')
GROUP BY DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, LogTime), 0);
```

Or `cross apply` to avoid repeating the calculation

```
SELECT X.[Hour], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM GPExportLog
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, LogTime), 0))) AS X ([Hour])
WHERE LogType like 'Success' AND (LogTime BETWEEN '2021-01-27' AND '2021-01-28')
GROUP BY X.[Hour];
```

Comment: Always felt wrong to me to use `datetime` like that, but I can't work out anything better than `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` which feels cumbersome. There has to be something better

Comment: @Charlieface are you referring to trying to truncate down to hour level?

Comment: Yes. Same issue with minutes, seconds, whatever. Just feels wrong to use `0` as a kind of `DateTime.MinValue`, and it doesn't work with `datetime2`. We have `EOMONTH`, why not `EOHOUR` etc?

Comment: @Charlieface I hadn't even noticed that TBH - the answer is just putting the same calculation in the group by - I hadn't actually noticed what it did.